# Finding username with Apache and PHP (REMOTE_USER)

Tags: php, apache, webserver, mod-auth-form

I use Apache's "mod_auth_form" module to authenticate users and it is working just fine. But now I need to figure out the user logged in to the web-site for some other application. I searched the web and found `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` variable in PHP. But I cannot get it to work. It does not return anything. Is there a way to get the `REMOTE_USER` variable to work? Or is there another way to find the user logged in via Apache's auth_form module? My environment "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)" and "PHP 7.3.13".

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I found the solution: To get the REMOTE_USER be populated, request must be made under a protected page. In short, I put the php file in private directory, and it worked. It would be nice to have it in all pages. However, I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: How is the user logged in? Using PHP sessions? To answer your question, we need to know how your login system works.

Comment: No, I don't use PHP sessions, the logins are handled by apache "AuthType form".

Comment: Have you looked at `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`?

Comment: Yes, also tried again now but no luck.

Comment: edit your question and show some code how you save logins and what you tried.

Comment: Hi @Dilek I edited my question as you suggest.